# Añadir elementos no seleccionados de un listbox a otro listbox

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

Tengo un formulario en Excel con varios listbox. Al seleccionar un elemento en el listbox A necesitaría pasar todos los elementos NO seleccionados al listbox B. Pero no consigo hacerlo. No tengo nada claro el procedimiento para recorrer el listbox A y si el elemento NO está seleccionado pasarlo al listbox B.

Pasar el elemento seleccionado si que lo tengo claro no así los no seleccionados.

Agradeceré cualquier ayuda.

Gracias.

Comment: Saludos. Incluye el código que llevas y que comportamiento tiene actualmente y cual debe ser; o en dado caso el error que se te muestra. Así te pueden guiar en como realizar lo que llevas.

Comment: Realmente no tenía nada montado. Estuve probando el viernes varias horas y no conseguía dar con la solución. Ha sido escribir la pregunta y se me ha encendido la bombilla :-)

Answer (score 1):

Por si sirve de ayuda en un futuro, esto es lo que he hecho:

```
'Elemento seleccionado
seleccion = Me.lst_ptl.ListIndex + 1
'Recorro el listbox
For i = 1 To Me.lst_ptl.ListCount
    'Si el elemento del listbox NO coincide con el elemento seleccionado lo añado al listbox de destino
    If i <> seleccion Then
    
        Me.lst_ubic_dest.AddItem Me.lst_ptl.List(i - 1)
        
    End If

Next i
```

Con eso añado al listbox destino cualquier elemento que no esté seleccionado.